# how do you find out what android resource is 0x7f040000 in eclipse?

Tags: android, resources

Over the course of programming I get errors that give a resource number like "0x7f040000" (or sometimes in decimal form)  My question is simple: **Is there an easy way to tell what resource that is in eclipse?**
i know i could manually identify every resource and print them out, but then every time i make a change to the program i'd have to update this code. Is there some way to search by resource ID?

Comment: @r brooks: Identifying what is causing the errors would make more sense. I've never personally seen errors which relate to a specific resource identifier - show some example code that causes such an error.

Comment: it only happend to me in some rare cases when I needed to be sure at runtime what ressources where loaded (like you randomly load a layout or an image, then you might want ot know if the right one loaded)

Comment: i didn't really need help with the error, i was getting frustrated having to write unnecissary code to figure out what resource it was talking about every time i got an error. my question was answered below. thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu look up the R class in the gen folder

for example

```
public final class R {
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int block=0x7f020000;
```

block is part or the drawables in the R file.

if you want to do this at runtime (and not just in the IDE of eclispe you can try

```
getResources().getResourceName(id);
```

Comment: thanks, been having to write lots of code printing things to the debug screen like ("screen1-> " + R.drawable.screen1) every time i got an error. this helps a lot thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can use [getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) for that:

```
getResources().getResourceName( theID )
```

Answer (score 1):

In your project structure, you should have a directory called `gen`. Browse that directory until you find the class `R`. There you find every resource of your project defined.

Another possibility is to go directly to the R class: Press ctrl + shift + T and in the popup you just type R. But be careful: There are at least two R classes listed there. One is from Android itself (package android.R) and your with the package name you have chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your R class and see what variable corresponds to that resource id.  Right click -> Go To Definition.